# how to save and restore the current adapter of listview

Tags: android, listview, screen, adapter

on android, ¿i can save and restore the current adapter of listview, when rotating the screen?
to make that i have to save the adapter in methode onSaveInstanceState, but how i can get the current adapter of my list activity?
thanks.

Comment: For what you save adapter? make it clear

Comment: and recreate it? the data is downloaded for web service, i can´t each time download the data, i wont save it, for not forgoting it.

Comment: while changing portrait to landscape. List again loading is i think this is ur question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to use a different layout in your activity when rotated, you can keep it from being recreated after a rotation in your manifest by adding :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

in your activity description in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Either (which you might not prefer) disable screen rotation

```
<activity android:name="YOUR ACTIVITY"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

or, after you got your data from the Web, save your Data in a ArrayList which you (after screen rotation) pass again to your adapter. Since you did it once you should already have your data somewhere...

Comment: thank you, i wont to change between portrait and landscape, without forgot the data.

Answer (score 0):

Make your adapter a class-wide variable and check if it's set on each orientation change (or for whatever reason your activity is restarting). If it's set, use this data adapter. If not, download the data again and save the downloaded stuff to the class-wide adapter.

Comment: tank you ColorWP.com for your idea